# Adding GIF with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a button in JS that generates random facts (strings) with a GIF or image to each fact to make it more fun.

I have one slight problem: photos/GIFs aren't displaying in my website.

```js
window.onload = () => {
    const factsArr = [
      {
        image: 'http://gph.is/153xv7h\250x300',
        content:"the horned lizard shoots out blood from its eyesockets when they feel danger is nearby"
      },
      {
        image: 'http://via.placeholder.com/200x100',
        content: "A Sesame Street episode (ep. 847) was aired on TV in 1976,it was so scary that the authorities had to pull it off due to several complaints from parents saying their children screamed in horror."
      }
    ];
  
    
    document.getElementById('generate-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
      const idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * factsArr.length);
      document.getElementById('random-fact-content').innerHTML = factsArr[idx].content;
      document.getElementById('random-fact-image').setAttribute('src', factsArr[idx].image)
    })
      
}
```

```html
<button id="generate-btn">Generate Random Fact</button>
<div id="random-fact-content"></div>
<img id="random-fact-image"/>
```

Comment: I removed the `script` tags from your JS code and it seems to be running fine in the snippet. What is your expected result?

Comment: I need the GIF to be displayed in my web page and it isnt

Comment: Have a look at your url. It's wrongly formatted. `http://gph.is/153xv7h\250x300` should be `http://gph.is/153xv7h/250x300`.

Comment: @Talal Khraisat, Along with it I think the URL doesn't point to a particular image file, try with a different URL.

Comment: oh it worked! when i used other direct link to the gif